# Show: $\mathcal{G}:=\left\{B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)|t+B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$ is $\sigma$-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $t\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
> >     $$
> > \mathcal{G}:=\left\{B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)|t+B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}
> > $$
> >     is a $\sigma$-Algebra.

I have to show:

1) $\mathbb{R}^n\in\mathcal{G}$, $\emptyset\in\mathcal{G}$

2) $G\in\mathcal{G}\Rightarrow\complement{G}\in\mathcal{G}$

3) $A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal{G}\Rightarrow\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\in\mathcal{G}$

ad 1) $\mathbb{R}^n\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (that's clear) and $t+\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}^n$, so $\mathbb{R}^n\in\mathcal{G}$.

But how can I show 2) and 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove the following theorem : Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$ and $f:X\to Y$ any function, then
$$
\{E \subset Y : f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M}\}
$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra. Now take $f(x) = x-t$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: A $\sigma$-Algebra on $X$ or on $Y$?

Comment: @math12: It consists of subsets of $Y$ so it can't really be a sigma-algebra on $X$, can it?

Comment: You are right. :-)

Comment: All right. I finished it. Thanks for your help, Prahlad Vaidyanathar and Stefan Hansen.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f:R^n\times R^n \to R^n$ defined by $f(x,y)=x-y$ is continuous. The restriction 
$f^{\star}$ of $f$ to the set $R^n \times \{t\}$ also is continuous because $R^n \times \{t\}$ is closed. Then it is obvious that $f^{\star}$ is Borel measurable in $R^n \times \{t\}$ which implies that $(f^{\star})^{-1}(B)$ is Borel measurable in   $R^n \times \{t\}$. If we get Borel set $B$ in $R^n$ then we get $(f^{\star})^{-1}(B)=(B+t)\times \{t\}$ is Borel subset of $R^n \times \{t\}$. The latter relation means that  $B+t$ is Borel subset in $R^n$. Since a set $B$ was taken arbitrary we conclude that $\cal{G}=B(R^n)$.