# Prove that the restriction of a Lebesgue measure on a subset is a complete measure

Tags: measure-theory

Given a Lebesgue measure $m$ on a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal M$ and Lebesgue measurable set $B$ let

$ \mathcal M_B = \{A \cap B\colon A \in \mathcal M\}$ and

$ m_B(A) = m(A) $

How do I first show that $\mathcal M_B$ is a $\sigma$-field on subsets of $B$.

1. $B$ belongs to $\mathcal M_B$ since $B = B \cap B $ and $B \in \mathcal M$
2. $ \bigcup_{i}(A_i \cap B) = (\bigcup_iA_i)\cap B $
3. How do I prove that if $A \cap B \in \mathcal M_B$, then $ (A \cap B) ^c \in \mathcal M_B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the solution to this problem : [Show: $\mathcal{G}:=\left\{B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)|t+B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$ is $\sigma$-Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466539/show-mathcalg-left-b-in-mathcalb-mathbbrntb-in-mathcalb-math), and apply it to the inclusion function from $B$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Prasad Vaidyanathan Thanks. Nice result that one. Although, the result I was trying to prove follows quite obviously from the definitions of $M_B$ and B. I was taking the complement with respect to R instead of B, which was causing difficulties.